# PDO "exception safety" and writing it to a log file PHP

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I am writing a PDO wrapper and having this issue with catching exceptions.

I am trying to maintain  *exception safety* practice,so I wanted to know how to catch an exception,writing it to a log file,and using exception safety to to do something, probably tell the user to retry action again or navigate to an error page or whatever (anything you can suggest).

So how is it done if possible?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I dont even have a code,I am having a hard time to write ADD,DELETE,UPDATE methods ,catching the error and doing the above,thats why I need your help,my wrapper now contains only a constructor.

Comment: You do know that PDO **is** the wrapper, right? You're wrapping a wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this code snippet, it shows how it is done:

```
class MyDb extends PDO 
{
  protected $error;

  function __construct( $logger )
  {
    try {
      parent::__construct( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );
      $this->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) {
       $this->error = $e->getMessage();
       // do your log writing stuff here
       $logger->Add( $this->error ); 
    }
  }
}
```

**update:**

usage of the class:

```
$logger = new MyLogger();
$db = new MyDb( $logger );
```

of course, you need a logger class with a add method:

```
class MyLogger
{
  const FILENAME = '/tmp/mylog.txt' ;

  function Add( $error )
  {
    file_put_contents( self::FILENAME, $error, FILE_APPEND);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only get the error message,what about preventing the script from collapsing,reacting the right way towards the user,and writing it to a log errors file ?

Comment: The example will not break down. It is good design to let a class handle a single task (separation of concerns). I update the example.

Comment: @JvdBerg: It's also good practice to allow methods to throw exceptions, and catch them at call time (and not inside of the method itself). That way you can be more flexible with what you do with the exception at the specific context in which it was thrown. (If a user has requested output, output a message, if it's an internal use, just log, etc).

Comment: Also (it's more of a convention thing), constant names should be UPPERCASED, method/function/variable names should be camelCase and class/object names should be PascalCased, just FYI :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I know .. I know .. :) it is just a simple example to get him started with OOP. I do not have te pretention to explain a decent OOP design in 40 lines of code.

Comment: I could not understand how this code escapes terminating the script ?
and how should I response to the user(in actuall code)

Comment: @GegrgergRgwg: Wow .. the short or the long version :) Handling user interaction is done in the `view` part of your application, while db handling is done in the `model` part of your app. The view can request the last error from the model, and display that.

Comment: Ok lets assume I understand what You said before,first there is a thing I know from c++ is to create an exception class and use it to catch errors and stuff,is there a better practice for handling exceptions than the above,the best one you know ?,then after catching the error I could simply ask the user to re try action? or the user current page will crash or not be displayed?

Comment: Well, it depends. If you can not create the `MyDb` class, you should abort. However, if a query fails due to invalid user input, you could retry. Handling is done in the `view` and you should initialize all stuff, go into the view, and then check what to do. In php there is also a global exception handler, but in a good design that is only a last resort, for catching unhandled exceptions.

Comment: So your saying that when $e contains an error I could use it anywhere in any php script?

Comment: $e is hidden in the class, but the `$db->error` can be used anywhere where there is access to `$db`