# Doesn't insert data in DB

Tags: php, pdo

Almost 2 days my computer doesn't want to insert data in my DB, tried to change a lot in code but still not works. (and deleted `  - and nothing changed). Could you suggest what is the reazon?

```
<?php
include '../db.php';
try {
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare(" INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`) VALUES (:login, :password) ");
   $stmt->bindParam(':login', $login );      
   $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password );
   $_POST['login'] = $login;
   $_POST['password'] = $password;
   $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch (exeption $e) { // Если ошибка - показать сообщение об ошибке
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "\nPDO::errorCode(): ", $dbh->errorCode();
echo "   ";
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
echo $num_rows;
/*header("location:../auth.php");*/
?>
```

> Returns PDO::errorCode(): 00000 (thats fine), but it returns 0 rows! Maybe that's the reason

And my db.php file:

```
<?php
try { //Connecting to db via login and password
$user = 'mydatabases';
$pass = '1234';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass); 
} 
catch (exeption $e) { //if any mistakes show message of error
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting error?

Comment: what r u getting in `echo $e->getMessage();` ???

Comment: from where u define `$login` and `$password`

Comment: i think u need to define these variable before binding them `$_POST['login'] = $login;
   $_POST['password'] = $password;` and change the possition as well. position or assignment is not correct.

Comment: You have your assignment backwards. `$_POST['login'] = $login;` should be `$login = $_POST['login'];`. New variable on the left, original value on the right.

Comment: @GufranHasan I get noghting in error()

Comment: check error logs ...

Comment: @devpro how...?

Comment: if u are not using then explore this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697438/pdo-exception-safety-and-writing-it-to-a-log-file-php

Answer (score 0):

In my DB was 2 extra columns I wanted them to be empty (they didnt fill when user register), that was the reason why code didnt work and didnt send me any error messages